# Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() - uploading photos form

Tags: php, html, file-upload, image-uploading

Hi I'm new to php and keep getting this error: "**Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/site/folder/upload.php on line 61.**"

I'm trying to build a form in which users can upload one or more photos automatically to a directory to then be displayed else where.

Whenever I use this form I created it functions properly on my website but unfortunately it keeps printing that error out and would like it to go away. Here is my code I'm working with:

```
 <div>
        <form action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
            <input type="file" name="images[]" multiple="multiple"/>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="upload images"/>
        <form/>
        <?php
                    // check if uploads directory exists
            $dir = "images/";
            if(!is_dir($dir))
            {
                            echo "Directory not found, let's create the folder.";
                            mkdir($dir,"0777", true);
            }

            $countimg = 0;
            $allimg = 0;
            foreach($_FILES["images"]["name"] as $k=>$name)
            {
                         $allimg++;
                         $imgname = $_FILES["images"]["name"][$k];
                         $sizeimg = $_FILES["images"]["size"][$k];
                         $tmpname = $_FILES["images"]["tmp_name"][$k];
                                 //2.
                         $extension = strtolower(pathinfo($dir.$imgname, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
                    if($extension=='png' || $extension=='jpg' ||$extension=='jpeg' ||$extension=='gif')
                                 {
                                        if($sizeimg < 2097152){
                                                        if(!file_exists($dir.$imgname)){
                                                                            //1.
                                                                    if(move_uploaded_file($tmpname,$dir.$imgname))
                                                                    {
                                                                                         $countimg++;
                                                                    }
                                                     }
                                        }
                         }
            }
            echo "You are trying to upload $allimg images".'<br>';
            echo "From $allimg image(s) - $countimg was/were uploaded with success".'<br>';
            $z = $allimg - $countimg;
            echo "$z image(s) were not uploaded: Not an image, over 2MB, or already uploaded.";

        ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: source code from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jbpmcsSD9co

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```php
if (count($_FILES)) {
    foreach($_FILES["images"]["name"] as $k=>$name) {
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: After trying count files it won't upload anything now. before it was uploading somehow with this error

Comment: throws some error? try to delete the files that are in the "images" folder (in case the file you are trying to upload now already exists)

Answer (score 0):

I tested your script, it works fine. The error message appears because you are not checking that a file got uploaded before starting the `foreach`. If I land on the page, the PHP code will still be triggered. To fix this, you may use the below:

```
<div>
        <form action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
            <input type="file" name="images[]" multiple="multiple"/>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="upload images"/>
        <form/>
        <?php

            if( $_POST['submit'] ) {

                $dir = "images/";
                if(!is_dir($dir))
                {
                                echo "Directory not found, let's create the folder.";
                                mkdir($dir,"0777", true);
                }

                $countimg = 0;
                $allimg = 0;
                foreach($_FILES["images"]["name"] as $k=>$name)
                {
                             $allimg++;
                             $imgname = $_FILES["images"]["name"][$k];
                             $sizeimg = $_FILES["images"]["size"][$k];
                             $tmpname = $_FILES["images"]["tmp_name"][$k];
                                     //2.
                             $extension = strtolower(pathinfo($dir.$imgname, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
                        if($extension=='png' || $extension=='jpg' ||$extension=='jpeg' ||$extension=='gif')
                                     {
                                            if($sizeimg < 2097152){
                                                            if(!file_exists($dir.$imgname)){
                                                                                //1.
                                                                        if(move_uploaded_file($tmpname,$dir.$imgname))
                                                                        {
                                                                                             $countimg++;
                                                                        }
                                                         }
                                            }
                             }
                }
                echo "You are trying to upload $allimg images".'<br>';
                echo "From $allimg image(s) - $countimg was/were uploaded with success".'<br>';
                $z = $allimg - $countimg;
                echo "$z image(s) were not uploaded: Not an image, over 2MB, or already uploaded.";

            }

        ?>
    </div>
```

`if( $_POST['submit'] )` will ensure that the form is submitted prior to running the rest of the PHP code.

Comment: This also works at getting rid of the error message but it won't upload the photos now. It say 0 were uploaded successfuly

Comment: Sorry I had made a slight edit to test the script, please use action="upload.php" instead of action="test.php" in the <form> tag

Comment: The original error occurs as the foreach is expecting to be given an array to work with. When no array has been added to the variable then the foreach just sees a normal variable instead of an array. Generally when you're going to load data into an array, firstly set the array up as an empty array eg $the_array = array(); which in that example would set $the_array up as an empty array.